# How do I write this in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

How do I write these symbols in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: \symbol{241} (the latex syntax for \char241)
check here: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf

Comment: This might be better suited to [tex.se], it doesn't seem to have a programming component.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the `mathabx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[
  \odiv
  \oplus
  \ominus
  \otimes
\]
    
\[
  \bigodiv
  \bigoplus
  \bigominus
  \bigotimes
\]
    
\end{document}
```

If you don't need the big versions, then the `stix` package would be another alternative.

[image]